# How to pass instance of REQUEST scoped service to global interceptor

Tags: angular, interceptor, nestjs

I am using `Nest JS` in Backend. I have logging service `scoped.Request`

```
@Injectable({ scope: Scope.REQUEST })
export class LoggingService extends BaseLoggerService implements LoggerService {
  constructor(readonly configService: ConfigurationService, @Inject(RequestContextService) readonly requestContextService: IRequestContextService) {}
```

I have global interceptor that required logging service.

```
@Injectable()
export class LoggingInterceptor implements NestInterceptor {
    constructor(@Inject(LoggingService) private readonly logger: LoggingService) {
    }  }
```

Now in app.ts, I am trying to define `useGlobalInterceptors` bypassing an instance of `Logging service`. However, It throws error on `npm run start`.

```
app.useGlobalInterceptors(new LoggingInterceptor(app.get(LoggingService)));
```

**Error**

```
2020-02-20T10:51:54.409Z ERROR [object Object] (RID:NOT_SET RP:NOT_SET TK:) (AN:NOT_SET COM:NOT_SET UAN:NOT_SET) LoggingService is marked as a scoped provider. Request and transient-scoped providers can't be used in combination with "get()" method. Please, use "resolve()" instead. Error: LoggingService is marked as a scoped provider. Request and transient-scoped providers can't be used in combination with "get()" method. Please, use "resolve()" instead.
```

Answer (score 2):

As the error states, as the `LoggerService` is `REQUEST` scoped, you need to use `await app.resolve<LoggingService>(LoggingService)`, however, what you'll probably want to do instead is bind the interceptor globally and let Nest take care of the dependency injection by adding the interceptor to a `providers` array like so:

```js
@Module({
  imports: [...],
  providers: [
    {
      provide: APP_INTERCEPTOR,
      useClass: LoggingInterceptor
    },
    ...
  ]
})
export class AppModule {}
```

Something to keep in mind is that the interceptor already has the entire request context available to it. Also, I'm not sure how enhancers function if they become REQUEST scoped (which is what will happen if it has a REQUEST scoped dependency) so keep in mind this may not be the best route forward.

Comment: Hey, thank for the answer. However I am facing one more issue. I am injecting REQUEST in RequestContextService, which is part of Logging Service. However when I debug in interceptor, instance of loggin service get created but Request always have null. Do you know  how to solve this

Comment: Like I said, I don't know if enhancers (that is interceptors, filters, guards, and pipes) can be request scoped. One option you have is to take the request from the interceptor and pass it to the logger so it can pass further down, but now you're working against the framework. Another route forward might be the better answer here